# Keyboard shortcut for Italian accents

Tags: shortcut-keys

UBUNTU 16.04 TLS.
I write in Italian language with an English keyboard. In italian language I must use the accents. I would like to set my keyboard for shotcut-keys. Anybody can help me?

Comment: Accents and shortcuts have nothing to do one with another. You just need to select the US International (or UK) **with dead keys**.

Comment: And you need to use the US keyboard layout (I mean with respect to software; not to switch the actual hardware-keyboard). In German, we have these nice characters: äöü. They are not part of the US-keyboard layout but I normally do programming work on US-keyboard layouts. Therefore, I switch the layout depending whether I write German texts or do programming.

Comment: I have done the selection of US international with dead keys. Now I don't understand where I can take the accents. I mean where are the accents for a, e, i, u and so on.

Comment: I finally understood. After I selected US international with dead keys, I have to push the two keys together: the vowel and the accent grave or acute. Thank you everybody